# Arrange list box in ascending order

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

Hi guys I am new to c# and I could really use some help here. I wish to arrange the items in my list box according to the highest to lowest and vice versa (they are interest rates) it is seen in this [picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HiTj.png)

I tried mutiple ways using array but none seems to work. I could use some help please.

My current code for reference:

```
namespace Group_Project_Final
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {


        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string DBS, OCBC, UOB, MayBank, HSBC, RHB;
            DBS = "1.60%";
            OCBC = "1.65%";
            MayBank = "1.62%";
            UOB = "1.55%";
            RHB = "1.68%";
            HSBC = "1.58%";
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add("Bank\t\tRates");
            listBox1.Items.Add("DBS" + "\t\t" + DBS );
            listBox1.Items.Add("OCBC" + "\t\t" + OCBC);
            listBox1.Items.Add("HSBC" + "\t\t" + HSBC);
            listBox1.Items.Add("RHB" + "\t\t" + RHB);
            listBox1.Items.Add("UOB" + "\t\t" + UOB);
            listBox1.Items.Add("May Bank" + "\t" + MayBank);

        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you agaisnt the idea of binding the list box to a list ob custom object than have some properties like (id , name , rating) and choose what properties is  display and witch is filter on.

Comment: @DragandDrop hi that is a great idea ! any pointers on how i can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `Dictionary` to store the bank name with his rate

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("HSBC","1.58%");
//so on
```

Next, to order rate, you just simply order by the value

```
var dictOrdered = dict.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Value);
```

Then add each item in `Dictionary` to the `ListBox`

```
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dictOrdered)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add($"{entry.Key} \t\t {entry.Value}");
    }
```

This works for your case particular by comparing the `string`, but normally, the right approach: you have to convert the value to `double` before comparing it

```
    //highest to low
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("HSBC","1.58%");
    var dictOrdered = dict.OrderByDescending(x=> double.Parse(x.Value.TrimEnd( new char[] { '%' })));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Items are shown in the order you add them, so you should order and then add them in that order.

Answer (score 0):

An approach for this problem that you could take is:

```
namespace Group_Project_Final
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Dictionary<string, double> interestRates;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            interestRates = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            interestRates.Add("DBS", 1.60);
            interestRates.Add("OCBC", 1.65);
            interestRates.Add("UOB", 1.55);
            interestRates.Add("May Bank", 1.62);
            interestRates.Add("HSBC", 1.58);
            interestRates.Add("RHB", 1.68);

            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox1.Items.Add("Bank\t\tRates");
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in interestRates)
            {
                listbox1.Items.Add($"{entry.Key}\t\t{entry.Value:0.##}%");
            }

        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //order interest rates either from high to low (descending)
            interestRates.OrderByDescending(item => item.Value);
            //or from low to high
            interestRates.OrderBy(item => item.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra class that will represent your BankRate data and Override the ToString() for simplicity.

```
public class bRate
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public double Percent;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id}: {Name}\t\t{Percent}";
    }

}
```

The in your your event you can use one of the following method.
The first one is to show the power and the simplicity of an extraclass.
The second is exactly what you need and will add the default item you need.

```
//Creating the list or reading it from database
var inputs = new List<bRate> {
    new bRate {Id = 1, Name= "DBS" , Percent=1.60},
    new bRate {Id = 2, Name= "OCBC", Percent=1.65},
    new bRate {Id = 3, Name= "UOB" , Percent=1.62},
};
```

Method 1: 1 Line

```
// Order the list base on the object property
// Simple list bind to ListBox and string overwrite
myListBox1.dataSource = inputs.OrderBy(x => x.Percent);

// exemple of ordering by Percent then by name if some bank have the same rate.
// inputs.OrderBy(x => x.Percent).ThenBy(x => x.Name)
```

Methode2: 3 Lines

```
// Add the First default item
myListBox2.Items.Add("Bank\t\tRates");
Add all the other
foreach (var item in inputs.OrderBy(x => x.Percent)) {
    myListBox2.Items.Add(item.ToString());
}
```